# How do I return value and end condition after first true in c++?

Tags: c++, if-statement, conditional-statements

I need to return the value for the first true and then end the condition.

Example code:

```
if (z > 0) 
return t;
return 0;
```

Where t is deemed as the month of projection and z is dependent of t. I would like this condition to return t when the first true is met and then end the condition (or 0 for next truths).

Alternatively this condition could enumerate the truths - return 1 after 1st true, 2 after second..

The case is I need to know at which t z is highier than 0 for the first time.

Comment: Sounds like you need to loop, incrementing `t` so that it is reflected in `z` for the next comparison -- and you will likely need more than one `if` condition within the loop to meet your requirement (which are quite unclear)

Comment: Could you give a specific example for z and t please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use bool variable for this. For example

```
bool first_true = false;

//Some condition that makes first_true = true

//Now just check if first_true is true or false
if(z > 0)
{
    if(first_true == true)
    {
       return t; 
    }
}
```

Also you can store this bool variable in a file so that your program remembers first true.

Comment: `=` is assignment, not comparison!

Comment: Sorry. I did not notice that. I edited the answer. Thanks for telling me

Answer (score 0):

to do so you need to store the state of validating the first time the z>0 condition, depending on the context you can do it by using a static variable,
here is a solution (where I assume both t and z are vars of integer type):

```
using namespace std;

static bool zBecameTrue = false;

int returnTwhenZBecameTrue(int z, int t)
{
    if(z > 0 && !zBecameTrue)
    {
        zBecameTrue = true;
        return t;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}


int main()
{
    int z = -1;
    int t = 10;

    cout<<returnTwhenZBecameTrue(z,t)<<endl;
    z++;
    cout<<returnTwhenZBecameTrue(z,t)<<endl;
    z++;
    cout<<returnTwhenZBecameTrue(z,t)<<endl;
    z++;
    cout<<returnTwhenZBecameTrue(z,t)<<endl;
    z++;
    cout<<returnTwhenZBecameTrue(z,t)<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

the output :

```
0                                                                                                                                                            
0                                                                                                                                                            
10                                                                                                                                                           
0                                                                                                                                                            
0
```